# Input on a webform, is it a "blank space" or "field"?

Tags: word-choice

What is the most correct english way for describing a input field/blank space on a webform/webpage?

It's for error message, ie "Please, fill out all fields" or "Please, fill out all blank spaces"

And allso describing rules about a field/blank space, ie "When this space is chosen show the space 'upload'"

I told it's "blank space", but it just sound wrong to me. (But im not native english speaker)

If its blank space, is it okay to shorten it down to just "space"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, it's a field. A blank space could be any unused area, really.
As web users may not be fully familiar with the term field, I would perhaps use "section" for public-facing pages, field for technical documentation..
I would also avoid "fill out" as that feels too AmEng, or at least too informal. "Complete" feels more international. No comma.

> Please complete all sections.

> [image]

Comment: Ah, this makes good sense. As a developer I got a more technical mindset, so guess that is why i like "field" better.

Comment: I don't think "fill out" is particularly "American".

Comment: @JamesK - I'd consider BrEng to be "fill in" not out, but I've added 'or too informal'. In BrEng, to fill out is to gain weight. I think we may have imported the US sense in recent times, but maybe I'm too old to think of it that way ;)